Uptime clock on ubuntu 22.04
I was looking for a way to display my running uptime next to my clock in Ubuntu. I wanted to see if there were any applications out there in the ubuntu ecosystem that already did this. If not I wanted to see if I could be pointed in the right direction for how I could implement this myself. Thanks!

In Extension Manager application search for Uptime Indicator
If not already installed you can do so in terminal as follows:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager

The app indicates uptime in the status area When clicked and a popup menu indicates the date when the system was started.


This is not available anymore I guess. Has anyone installed it recently in jammy?

@NaveedAhmed Uptime is no longer supported but Uptime Indicator (a different app) is, supported versions being 3.4.1 through 46. Did you check before posting your comment?

Yes, I am able to download the desired version as a zip file. But I wanted to install it from the website/software store. And it said “no such native application.org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell”.

@NaveedAhmed are you looking in the right place? As mentioned in the answer, install Extension Manager use the Browse tab to find it and simply click on the Install button alongside it. If ypou are using GNOME Extensions in the likes of Firefox or Chromium, you are looking in the wrong place. There is no need to download it as a .zip file.
